# is there a better alternative to List<T> initalization than invoking Arrays.asList?

Tags: java

Is there a better alternative to using Arrays.asList as a List bulk initializer?  Of concern is that this one is verbose and involves an extraneous class and method.

```
List<Double> myList = new ArrayList<Double>(Arrays.asList(3.01d, 4.02d, 5.03d));
```

Edit: This question pertains to a bulk initialization which would usually have more than the three values shown in the example.

Comment: This looks perfectly fine (as well as the optimization suggested by MatrixFrog, if the list will be read-only).  A single method call is in an initialization is not going to make a difference, performance-wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know that you won't need to add anything to the list later, you can just do

```
List<Double> myList = Arrays.asList(3.01d, 4.02d, 5.03d);
```

I'm pretty sure the list returned from `Arrays.asList` can be modified, but only in that you can change the elements that are there -- you can't add new elements to it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/),

```
List<Double> myList = Lists.newArrayList(3.01d, 4.02d, 5.03d));
```

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't match the question 100%, but adding this answer in case the wanting to instatiate a List was just to be able to immediately do something with the values in it, vs. just instantiating a List for the sake of just doing the instantiation alone.

With Java 8 you can use [`Stream.of(T... values)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-), then manipulate the steam via the stream API to get the results you would want from the list of values.

For example, to get the max value of a series of values ...

`int maxValue = Stream.of(10, 5, 25).max(Integer::compareTo).get();`

The above example is also helpful for when you want `Math.max(#,#)` type functionality, but have more than two arguments to process.

Comment: thanks for sharing.
I think `Stream.of(object).collect(Collectors.toList())` is the better way.

Comment: @AliReza19330 How so? Seems like you have extra unneeded steps of collecting then putting the values into a List.

Comment: Maybe my use case is a bit different. In my use case the result of `Stream.of(object).collect(Collectors.toList())` was a mutable collection. but `Arrays.asList` is immutable. However, as per java doc of the first one there is no guarantee of mutability of the first one, for the mutability guarantee we should use `toCollection`

Answer (score 2):

Since java 9 you are able to use `List.of` factory method:

```
static <E> List<E> of​(E... elements)
```

> Returns an immutable list containing an arbitrary number of elements.

Or use guava:

```
public static <E> ImmutableList<E> of(E e1, E e2,...)
```

> Returns an immutable list containing the given elements, in order.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be as an anonymous inner class:

```
List<Double> myList = new ArrayList() {
{
   add(3.01d);
   add(4.02d);
   add(5.03d);
}
};
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear that it is a bulk initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
List<Double> myList = Arrays.asList(new Double[]{3.01d, 4.02d, 5.03d});
// or
List<Double> myList = Arrays.asList(3.01d, 4.02d, 5.03d);
```

Comment: Allocating the `Double[]` is not necessary, because `Arrays.asList` has a "varargs" form.

Comment: It's important to note that the list returned by `Arrays.asList(...)` is backed by the given array and therefore *fixed-length*. To demonstrate, try calling `myList.add(1.0d)` after initializing the list and you'll get an UnsupportedOperationException. If you want to add more elements to the list at some point, pass the result of the `asList(...)` method to `ArrayList`'s copy constructor.